# migrate to keycloak from spring boot security

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

i want to migrate to keycloak from my old spring boot security app.Below is my security config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.csrf().disable();

         http
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/*", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/school-admin/*").hasAuthority("SCHOOL_ADMIN").anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
             .antMatchers("/teacher/*").hasAuthority("TEACHER").anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
             .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

         .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login.html").defaultSuccessUrl("/loginSuccess.html")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?error").permitAll().and()

         .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout.html")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html?logout");

     }

     @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }
}
```

I have already installed the keycloak and it is running on port 8080.The problem I found out that, we should create role and user on keycloak admin page, But what my current system is, users and roles are on my MySQL DB. I don't want to insert the users and roles on keycloak for authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, obviously the first thing is a running keycloak instance, I assume this should be doable with the online documentation. We use i.e. Keycloak on a Wildfly instance.
Next step is to define a realm and at least one client in keycloak that you will use to connect to with your spring-boot application. In you application's POM you will need to add dependencies for a keylcoak adapter like i.e.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat8-adapter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-adapter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The rest can be done in your application.properties, that's the place where you configure how the adapter connects to keycloak and which parts of your application should be secured. This can look like

```
keycloak.realm=myrealm #realm that you have created in keycloak, contains your client
keycloak.auth-server-url=KeycloakHOST:KeycloakPort/auth # Substitute with your settings
keycloak.ssl-required=none
keycloak.resource=myclient
#keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.enable-basic-auth=true # we use basic authentication in this example
keycloak.credentials.secret=2dcf74ca-4e4f-44bf-9774-6c32c12783d3 # Secret generated for you client in keycloak
keycloak.cors=true
keycloak.cors-allowed-headers=x-requested-with,origin,content-type,accept,authorization
keycloak.cors-allowed-methods=GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS
keycloak.cors-max-age=3600
keycloak.expose-token=true
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=adminRule
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].authRoles[0]=SCHOOL_ADMIN
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/school-admin/*
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].name=teacherRule
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].authRoles[0]=TEACHER
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/teacher/*
```

That's basically all you need to do in your spring-boot application. All other endpoints not covered by the rules above remain available to all. You can find a pretty good tutorial on that [here](http://slackspace.de/articles/authentication-with-spring-boot-angularjs-and-keycloak/) that is the longer version what I have described.

Comment: yes i have started the keycloak. But the problem is all the user's credentials are on my db, not on keycloak. So how can i make keycloak check with my db for authentication and authorization?

Comment: You can write a custom provider, I haven't done that by myself before but it should be possible. See https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-adminstration-guide/content/topics/user-federation/custom.html for some info, maybe google for it a little bit. In general, there should be an interface that you will need to implement and this implementation will go to your DB and query for the user data given there. Only question is if you can provide all the data that is needed by the interface, but you need to check that.

Comment: I just found an even better example using some DB connected with JPA, see https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/user-storage-jpa in the end this is also the big advantage of having this FDI capabilities in keycloak, cause you can plug several providers and use them together.

Comment: I will check that, did you found any spring boot example??

Comment: The custom provider is not a spring boot thingy, it's plain Java EE wildfly topic. For your spring-boot application that's happening completely transparent, meaning you don't need to do anything with the adapter or the config that you have there. Behind the curtains (keycloak as FDI system) you are introducing your DB as a custom source for authentication/authorization information.

Comment: @hecko84 thank you for this answer. can you describe how to exclude endpoint from security? for example, I need to secure all /user* endpoints except /user/registration. how to do this?

Comment: Hm, it's some time ago that I worked on that, but I haven't seen a different usage then I described above. We had some how similar requirements, but solved it by having a different endpoint strategy like i.e. /public/user/registration for freely available resources

Comment: updated link for @hecko84 posts - https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/user-storage-jpa